# Why can't initialize the static member in a class in the body or in the header file?

Tags: c++

Could any body offer me any reason about that?

If we do it like that, what's the outcome? Compile error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that static initialization isn't just initialization, it is also *definition*.  Take for example:

### hacks.h :

```
class Foo
{
public:
    static std::string bar_;
};

std::string Foo::bar_ = "Hello";

std::string GimmeFoo();
```

### main.cpp :

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

#include "hacks.h"

using std::string;
using std::ostringstream;
using std::cout;

int main()
{
    
    string s = GimmeFoo();
    return 0;
}
```

### foo.cpp :

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

#include "hacks.h"

using std::string;
using std::ostringstream;
using std::cout;

string GimmeFoo()
{
    Foo foo;
    foo;
    string s = foo.bar_;

    return s;
}
```

In this case, you can't initialize `Foo::bar_` in the header because it will be allocated in every file that `#include`s hacks.h.  So there will be 2 instances of `Foo.bar_` in memory - one in main.cpp, and one in foo.cpp.

The solution is to allocate & initialize in just one place:

### foo.cpp :

```
...
std::string Foo::bar_ = "Hello";
...
```

Answer (score 5):

It is just a limitation in the language it self. Hopefully, when C++0x becomes reality, this limitation would go away.

[I think this page gives a somehow good reason](http://www.acm.org/crossroads/xrds2-4/ovp.html#SECTION00040000000000000000):

> One of the trickiest ramifications of
>   using a static data member in a class
>   is that it  must be initialized, just
>   once, outside the class definition, in
>   the source file. This is due to the
>   fact a header file is typically seen
>   multiple times by the compiler. If the
>   compiler encountered the
>   initialization of a variable multiple
>   times it would be very difficult to
>   ensure that variables were properly
>   initialized. Hence, exactly one
>   initialization of a static is allowed
>   in the entire program.

Comment: To expand a bit, if the same static is initialized in multiple places, the linker would have to verify that they all initialize to the same value.  Given that the initialization expression may be arbitrarily complex (including function calls) and not compile-time computable, this would be impossible.

Answer (score 0):

> Why can't we initializer a static data member in the class body or in the header file

We can, starting from C++17 we can use `inline` keyword to **define** a static data member right inside the class without any need to initialize it later outside the class.

For example, we can have the following in c++17

```
#include <string>

struct C
{
   static inline std::string var = "initializer inside class";
};
//no need for initialization here outside the class
```