# LNK2001 error in code

Tags: c++, linker-errors, lnk2001

I am getting LNK2001 error. The code has been included below. Can someone please help me out?

```
Error   3   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "private: static class   std::vector<struct _UpdateAction,class std::allocator<struct _UpdateAction> > InstrumentCache::actionTaken" (?actionTaken@InstrumentCache@@0V?$vector@U_UpdateAction@@V?$allocator@U_UpdateAction@@@std@@@std@@A)    PerformanceTest.obj
```

//UpdateAction.h

```
typedef struct _UpdateAction
{
    enum FIS_ACTION {
        ADDED,
        UPDATED,
        DELETED
    };
    int id;
    int type;
    int legacyType;
    FIS_ACTION action;

}UpdateAction;

typedef std::vector<UpdateAction> ActionTakenVector;
```

// InstrumentCache.h

```
#include UpdateAction.h

class InstrumentCache
{
public:
    static ActionTakenVector& GetApplicationUpdateVector ()
    {
    return actionTaken;
    }

    static void ClearApplicationUpdateVector()
    {
        actionTaken.clear();
    }
private:
    static ActionTakenVector actionTaken;
};
```

//fisClient.h

```
#include "UpdateAction.h"
#include "InstrumentCache.h"

class FISClient
{
    void FunctionOne()
    {
        ActionTakenVector& rV = InstrumentCache::GetApplicationUpdateVector();
        InstrumentCache::ClearApplicationUpdateVector();
    }
} ;
```

PerformanceTest.cpp

```
#include "fisClient.h"
```

Comment: For a related recent post, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2470737/why-cant-initialize-the-static-member-in-a-class-in-the-body-or-in-the-header-fi

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unresolved external symbol on static class members](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/195207/unresolved-external-symbol-on-static-class-members)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you are missing the definition of actionTaken (the declaration in the class is not enough). Does adding

ActionTakenVector InstrumentCache::actionTaken;

in PerformanceTest.cpp help?

Comment: Oh, right - defined, not initialized.  Well, initialized, too.  Hard to keep terminology straight sometimes.

Answer (score 2):

Static members need to be initialized.  Somewhere outside your class, you should write `ActionTakenVector InstrumentCache::actionTaken`, which should initialize that static field and get rid of your error.